# How do I write to a class member variable through a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am writing a very simple pathfinder-type game.

For that purpose, I have the following class for the main player:

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, **player):
        self.name = ""
        self.health = 100
        self.attack = 0
        self.defense = 0
        self.speed = 0
        self.inventory = []
        self.__dict__.update(player)

    @property
    def attributes(self):
        return {
            "health": self.health,
            "attack": self.attack,
            "defense": self.defense,
            "speed": self.speed,
        }
```

I also have an Item class:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, **item):
        self.name = ""
        self.influenced_attribute = ""
        self.amount = 0
        self.__dict__.update(item)
```

What I would now like to be able to do is have a `use` member function for my `Player` class like this:

```
def use(self, item):
    self.attributes[item.influenced_attribute] += item.amount
    self.remove(item)
```

Unfortunately, this does not change the players attributes.

This, on the other hand, does:

```
def use(self, item):
    infl_attr = item.influenced_attribute
        if infl_attr == "health":
            self.health += item.amount
        elif infl_attr == "attack":
            self.attack += item.amount
        elif infl_attr == "defense":
            self.defense += item.amount
        elif infl_attr == "speed":
            self.speed += item.amount

    self.remove(item)
```

Why is that, and is there a way to implement something like the first version?

Comment: @property is a getter. It's returning a new dict with each invocation. You need to implement the setter as well.

Comment: Why do you want this behavior to begin with? What is the purpose of returning a `dict` of the object's attributes? *just use the object*

Comment: `self.attributes[item.influenced_attribute] += item.amount` doesn't work because you merely change the *key* of the `dict` returned by `self.attributes`. You never do anything with the dict. Again, **why do things this way**? If you want to use a string, `item.influenced_attribute` to modify an object's attribtue, use `getattr` and `setattr`. So `setattr(self, item.influenced_attribute) = getattr(self.item.influenced_attribute) + item.amount`

Comment: IOW, the dict does **not hold the member *variable***, it holds a reference to an object that happens to be referenced by a member variable. But making the dict contain a reference to a different value won't change the value the member variable references.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, this does exactly what I needed! I had not know about `getattr` and `setattr` before.